# using mcp3008I/P adc with raspberrypi

Tags: analog, adc, converter, data, speed

```
def analogInput(channel):
   spi.max_speed_hz = 3571
   adc=spi.xfer2([1,(8+channel)<<4,0])
   data = ((adc[1]&3)<<8) + adc[2]
   return data
def Volts(data):
   volts=(data*3.3)/float(1024)
   volts=round(volts,2)
   return volts
```

I'm using the mcp3008 for raspberrypi. I built DC/DC converter, and in the output I put divider voltage and the maximum value that ADC can get is 3V in CH0. I want to display this voltage in my LCD, so my problem that I have a deviation. I think that the problem in the define of `spi.max_speed_hz = ?`, how I define that due to what?

[image]

Comment: Do you understand why we add schematics to questions?

Comment: I agree. 80% of your text is to explain to us how your circuit is wired.
Please remove that text and add a schematics instead. Your question would be much clearer and may get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `gpiozero` library in python to interface with it.
You can do this with:

```
from gpiozero import MCP3008

pin_which_i_am_looking_at = MCP3008(<your pin number here>)
[…]
value = pin_which_i_am_looking_at.value
```

As far as I know, this should work.
Have fun with your MCP3008!

Comment: the value that i get is lower than 1 , i shoulg get numbers from 0 to 1023 right?

Comment: You could map the values from 0 to 1023 with `value = (1023 * pin_which_i_am_looking_at.value)`

Comment: so i dont work with SPI?

Comment: No, the module does work with SPI, but it handles all of the math and other stuff for you.